# How to disable Right Click in Devexpress XtraOpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, devexpress, openfiledialog

I am using devexpress openFileDialog which is called XtraOpenFileDialog. I need to disable Right Click in this control but can't a way for do that! There is no property or event to handle that. 
Does anybody know about this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no way to disable the default right-click context menu in the DevExpress dialogs.

If you have a subscription that allows access to the source code you can disable the invocation of the ShowContextMenu method in the ViewController class's MouseUp method.

```
public void MouseUp(MouseButtons mouseButtons, IContextMenuProvider contextMenuProvider) {
    if((mouseButtons & MouseButtons.RightButton) == MouseButtons.RightButton) {
        ShowContextMenu(contextMenuProvider);  //Remove this
    }
}
```